# How to format string date and get string as result?

Tags: android, datetime

I have a date as a string in format `2013-02-12T20:52:20Z` and I want to get string `20:52 12 Feb 2013`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(yourStringDate);
String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd MMM yyyy").format(date);
```

Comment: I got this error: "The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String datemillis = "2013-02-12T20:52:20Z";
            SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            try {
                convertedDate = format.parse(datemillis);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```